# Merge two objects obtained from firebase realtime database with javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, foreach, javascript-objects

I need to merge two received objects (lists) from the firebase real-time database for further iteration through foreach.

I've tried something like
`snapshot1.concat (snapshot2)`

and

```
Object.assign ({}, snapshot1, snapshot2);
```

but ended up getting the error foreach is not a function.

How can I do that?

Comment: Don't give us a single line of code please, as we have no idea how the variables are initialized, nor can we see where `forEach` is used. Instead show us the minimal-but-complete code with anyone can reproduce the problem. I highly recommend spending some time reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following that guidance is the best way to increase the chances someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each snapshot is a [`DataSnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#haschild), there is no built-in way to merge the results of two or more snapshots together.

To iterate over every child of one or more snapshots, you'd first build an array of the `DataSnapshot` objects and then iterate over them, iterating over each of their children.

```js
([snapshot1, snapshot2])
  .forEach(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
      // do something with each child
    })
  });
```

You could also abstract this logic depending on what you are doing:

```
function getChildren(...snapshots) {
  const children = [];
  snapshots.forEach(aSnapshot => 
    aSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot =>
      children.push(childSnapshot)
    )
  );
  return children;
}

const children = getChildren(snapshot1, snapshot2);
children.forEach(childSnapshot => {
  // do something with each child
})
```

```
function getValuesOfChildren(...snapshots) {
  const children = [];
  snapshots.forEach(aSnapshot => 
    aSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot =>
      children.push(childSnapshot.val()) // or { key: childSnapshot.key, ...childSnapshot.val() }
    )
  );
  return children;
}

const children = getValuesOfChildren(snapshot1, snapshot2);
children.forEach(childData => {
  // do something with each child
})
```

```
function joinSnapshots(...snapshots) {
  return {
    // add/remove methods as needed
    exists: () => snapshots.some(aSnapshot => aSnapshot.exists()),
    forEach: (action) => snapshots.forEach(snapshot => snapshot.forEach(action)),
    hasChildren: () => snapshots.some(aSnapshot => aSnapshot.hasChildren()),
    numChildren: () => snapshots.reduce((sum, aSnapshot) => sum + aSnapshot.numChildren(), 0)
  }
}

const jointSnapshot = joinSnapshots(snapshot1, snapshot2);
jointSnapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
  // do something with each child
})
```